# verilog program will only work if sensitivity list is (posedge clock)

Tags: fpga, verilog

I have a program in Quartus Lite 19.1 that will only work if a particular always block uses posedge of clock sensitivity. If I try to use an (star) sensitivity list then it does not, even though this makes more sense.

My program takes in 32 bits of data and a write signal. The Fpga takes the 32 bits where [31:24] are an op code and [7:0] are the actual data, and stores them in wires. Another always block decodes the top most bits (opcode) and writes according to the opcode. This is the block that needs to have the posedge clock sensitivity. I do not understand why this is the case. I originally had it as a (*) sensitivity list and it took me forever to realize that this was the problem.

I think there is some fundamental reason that this does not work and I cannot see it. I have posted a part of the code below. Note the last always block does work without posedge of clock sensitivity, which confuses me even more.

```
assign opcode = temp_op[31:24];
assign write_data = temp_data[7:0];

always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (write) begin
        temp_op <= D; 
        temp_data <= D;
    end
end

//decode input 
always @(posedge clock) begin //has to be posedge clock otherwise it will not work
      if (opcode == 8'b00000010) Enc_delay <= write_data & delay_mask;
      else if (opcode == 8'b00000001) mode <= write_data & mode_mask;
      else pulse_width <= write_data & pulse_width_mask;    
end

//decode delay 
 always @ (Enc_delay) begin
      if (Enc_delay == 8'b00000001) delay = 250;//5us
      else if (Enc_delay == 8'b00000010) delay = 500;//10us
  else if (Enc_delay == 8'b00000011) delay = 1000;//20us
      else delay = 8'd125;    end //2.5us
```

Update:

I have not simulated, which I know is bad but I am monitoring the outputs which I have routed out through pins (using DE10 nano development board). My program is a pulse width generator with variable delay, pulse width and different modes for triggering the pulses. When I say it does not work, I mean I get no signals at my outputs.

Comment: Does it work correctly in simulation?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the manner in which it "does not work"? If the logic in that `always` block is not sensitive to a clock edge, then you're creating a whole lot of asynchronous latches, which is generally a Really Bad Idea in an FPGA, which is optimized for synchronous logic.

Comment: Can you draw (schematic or block diagram) the logic you are trying to infer?

Comment: I will try to simulate. Could you please elaborate more on 

> 
If the logic in that always block is not sensitive to a clock edge, then you're creating a whole lot of asynchronous latches, which is generally a Really Bad Idea in an FPGA, which is optimized for synchronous logic
> 

The variables "opcode" and "write_data" are sensitive to a clock edge, but I do not understand why I would be creating latches. Is the if/else not a good idea with combinational logic?
Thanks

Comment: Can I elaborate? Not in any meaningful way without knowing something about your level of education and experience on this topic. Otherwise, it would be far too broad to address here.

Comment: Well Dave, when you have an intimate understanding of something you can explain it to a 5 year old, and I am older than 5.

Comment: Ok, since you're older than 5, if you have some paths thorugh a process that assign to a signal, and others that don't, you create a latch.